# auto indent text from the right on every new line

Tags: css

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ny5Uy/)

```
<div class='outer'>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='ShowSmiley();' class='emojie'>
<img src="images/smiley.png" height="20px" width="20px"></a>
<div class="emoji-menu" id="emojiMenu" style="display:none;" >
  </div>
 <div contenteditable="true" id='MsgToSend' onkeypress='ClientOnTyping(event);'class='msgtosend'></div>
  <style>
  .msgtosend /* The message to send div */
  {
display:block;
border:1px solid Gray;

height:100px;
width:270px;
max-width:270px;          
overflow:auto;
word-wrap:break-word;

}
 .outer
{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
 .outer .emojie
{

padding-top: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
border:none;
}
</style>
```

how should i make my editable div auto indent from the right on every insertion of a new line ?? by 20 px let's say

Comment: do you want the text direction to be right to left? or do you just want a space between the right edge of the div and the text that is inserted?

Comment: a space on the right edge of the div and the text that is inserted should take that space too automatically on insertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might not be understand your problem fully but
if you want to align your text right you can just use text-align property and padding-right will make sure it's distance with right

```
div
{
    background-color:Red;
    padding-right:20px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Have a look [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jQ7P/1/)

Edit :

If you want to insert text from right to left then use direction property

```
 direction:rtl;
```

here is the updated code [Update JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ny5Uy/1/)

Comment: that is not what i'm looking for it's like the textarea used in skype when u insert a text and reached the end of the textarea you can see that the text is automatically indent from the right without getting under the emoji image

Comment: @Sora Please look into this updated fiddle and let me know if any thing wrong with it.. thanks

Comment: @Sora one more thing as you said in your previous comment.you want it like as skype chatbox so here is the update fiddle for that too       http://jsfiddle.net/ny5Uy/4/. in this if you want left to right text then remove direction property.

Comment: yes thank you that what i was looking for sorry for being late